# Read GPIO Register

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, gpio

I want to read GPIO GPLEV0 register in raspberry pi (for input). However using Wiring Pi does not help since it return one pin not the register value (read all option also is not good option I want to read exactly the GPLEV0 register).

How to directly read the entire 32bit value in the GPLEV0 register at once without using wiring pi library?

Comment: I don't know if the registers in the Raspberry Pi are memory mapped or not, but if you know the address of the register and it is memory mapped, you can use a program called [devmem2](http://www.lartmaker.nl/lartware/port/devmem2.c).

Comment: There also appear to be useful links at [this web page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=43023).

Comment: @dwelch Which particular sample you are referring in this repo?

Comment: @Steve Thanks Steve, I am going to try the devmem2, I guess it can solve the problem!. But I will let everybody know.

Comment: You mentioned wiring pi, which of course has the answer, but sounds like you wanted a linux solution so nevermind...

Comment: @dwelch You are right, I had to explicitly mention that I was looking for linux solution.